# Getting strange timeouts when trying to connect to registry.gitlab while at ci\cd pipline. How can I debug and what could cause this?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns

About a week ago my gitlab pipeline started failing because of strange timeout errors while connecting to registry.gitlab:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Settings for this pipline haven't been changed for about a year, so it shouldn't be the source of problem. I'm also not getting any error messages from gitlab, just timeouts, so I think the problem is not some kind of ratelimits either. I tried changing dns. First from default to google. It helped and everything was fine for a couple of hours, but than I started to get timeouts again, so I changed nameservers from google to cloudflare, but it didn't work this time... setting up vpn also helped for a couple of hours. I think that I have some strange network problem, but I don't know how can I debug this or what could cause this behavior at all. What should I try?

I use ubuntu 22.04 on the server.

Comment: You should contact GitLab support.

Comment: But I don't think it is actually gitlab problem, like I described it seems that is more sort of a networking problem, but I'll contact them, thanks for advice